# Can't modify existing registry key

Tags: vb.net, registry, registrykey

```
Private POWER_HIGHPERFORMANCE As String = "6f28993d-6925-4551-a659-2140ba44e835"
Private POWER_BALANCED As String = "381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e"

Dim RegKeyActivePowerScheme As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes", True, Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl)
        RegKeyActivePowerScheme.SetValue("ActivePowerScheme", POWER_HIGHPERFORMANCE, RegistryValueKind.String)
        RegKeyActivePowerScheme.Close()
```

I can't modify it to high performance plan. I just get an error "The specified RegistryKeyPermissionCheck value is invalid. Parameter name: mode

Comment: Are you running this on an OS with UAC?

Comment: Yeah. I require administrator while running the application. (Using Win 7)

Comment: It's a permission issue because when I manually modify the permissions to "Full Control" it works fine.